# I cant import a telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

[that's the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph9fX.png)
I can not import these imports telegram into python
I downloaded telegram-bot but still doesn't work
tried to download venv and there to download telegram-bot but doesnt help :(
tried to update telegram-bot and again doesn't work :(

Comment: Please don't [upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Use the **Edit** button and share the code and the error.

Answer (score -1):

Check version compatibility: Verify that you have a compatible version of python-telegram-bot installed. Check the version requirements specified by your code or documentation. You can use the following command to check the installed version.

```
pip show python-telegram-bot
```

Verify module name: Make sure you are importing the correct module name. In your Python script, use the following import statement.

```
import telegram
```

Check Python environment: Confirm that you are executing the script in the same Python environment where python-telegram-bot is installed. If you are using a virtual environment (venv), make sure it is activated before running the script. You can activate a virtual environment using the following command `source <venv>/bin/activate`  replace the venv with ur actual directory.

Comment: checked that too

Comment: please provide more details about your development environment, such as the Python version you're using and the IDE or editor you're working with.

Comment: Doestn helped sadly :(. I have no idea from where the error comes